# How to make this function work in views.py of django?

Tags: python, html, django

I want to make this `Destination()` function work with multiple variables because I don't want to write it again and again. I made it equal with two variables but it is not working. How to solve this problem?

```
def index(request):
    a,b = Destination()
    a.desc = 'Hello, How are you!'
    a.img = '01.jpg'

    b.desc = 'Hello, How are you!'
    b.img = '02.jpg'

    target = [a,b]

    context = {
     'target': target
    }
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

Comment: Share your destination function as well as the exception you get.

Comment: What is a `Destination()` here? Based on the formatting, that should be a class?

Comment: It's giving me TypeError at /

Comment: @Ali: likely because `Destination(..)` is an object that is not an iterable)

Comment: Post the full error, also the code for Destination please.

Comment: I made a class by the name of ```Destination``` in ```models.py``` and imported it in ```views.py``` so that I could write and make the html page dynamic.

Comment: @Ali, `Destination()` returns you a new class instance, which if is not iterable will throw error.

Comment: I didn't understand Saket.

Comment: `a, b = [1, 2]` will work, as [1, 2] is a `list` and it is iterable that means, it can be iterated over. but `Destination()` returns you a single value that is **instance** of class `Destination`. so, python doesn't know what to assign to `a` and what to `b`

Answer (score 4):

If you write `a, b = ...` you perform [*iterable unpacking* [PEP-3132]](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/). Since a `Destination` object is likely not iterable, that will not work.

You can use list comprehension for example to generate two `Destination`s here, this will even skip the need of assigning `target = [a, b]` a second time:

```
def index(request):
    target = a, b = [Destination() for __ in range(2)]
    a.desc = 'Hello, How are you!'
    a.img = '01.jpg'

    b.desc = 'Hello, How are you!'
    b.img = '02.jpg'

    context = {
     'target': target
    }
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

and given the `desc` is a parameter of the constructor of `Destination(..)`, you can omit that as well:

```
def index(request):
    target = a, b = [Destination(desc='Hello, How are you!') for __ in range(2)]
    a.img = '01.jpg'
    b.img = '02.jpg'

    context = {
     'target': target
    }
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

Stricly speaking, you could make some sort of generator, like:

```
def generator(f, n, *args, **kwargs):
    return [f(*args, **kwargs) for __ in range(n)]
```

Then the above can be substituted with:

```
def index(request):
    target = a, b = generator(Destination, 2, desc='Hello, How are you!')
    a.img = '01.jpg'
    b.img = '02.jpg'

    context = {
     'target': target
    }
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

This thus slightly reduces the amount of boilerplate code, although it might make it less readable, since now the reader will need to inspect the `generator` function first.

Comment: What if I want to add multiple different descriptions?

Comment: @Ali: then you simply do not use `desc=...` at the list comprehension level/`generator`, and set the `a.desc = ...` and `b.desc = ...`.

Comment: Hey william, whenever I increase c,d and so on and give the images more then it repeats the images. Why?

Comment: @Ali: you did change it to `range(4)`? You did *not* use `a = b = ... = Destination()`, right? Because then you did not construct separate objects, but just refrenced the same object multiple times.